# Erlang: receive multiple multicast streams on the same port

Tags: sockets, erlang, udp, multicast

I have a multicast-based IPTV in my network.
All channels have muticast addresses like 239.0.1.*.
Streamer device sends UDP data to target port 1234.
So to receive a tv stream I do usual stuff like:

```
{ok, S} = gen_udp:open(1234, ....
inet:setopts(S, [{add_membership, {{239,0,1,2}, {0,0,0,0}}}]),
```

It works.

Now I want to subscribe to multiple channels to receive several streams simultaneously.
So I do another call:

```
inet:setopts(S, [{add_membership, {{239,0,1,3}, {0,0,0,0}}}]),
```

It works too. I see both streams in Wireshark. I can distinguish them by destination IP addresses - 239.0.1.2 and 239.0.1.3.

BUT.

In Erlang I cant figure out a channel to which incoming packet belongs, cause UDP data arrives as messages:

```
{udp, Socket, IP, PortNo, Packet},
```

where IP and PortNo is the source address (10.33.33.32 in my case) and port (49152).

So the question is - how to determine destination IP address of incoming multicast UPD packet.

Windows 7, Erlang 5.9/OTP R15B.

Thanks!

Comment: You might consider asking this on erlang-questions if you don't get an answer here.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746257/how-to-send-multicast-messages-and-reuse-a-port-in-erlang

Comment: Ricardo, at first I thought you post a link to point me to an answer. But now I guess you wanted me to give you an advise. Unfortunately, I cant help you.

Answer (score 0):

This should retrieve the destination IP from received UDP data:

```
{udp, Socket, IP, PortNo, Packet},
{ok, {Address, Port}} = inet:sockname(Socket),
```

Address will contain tuple like {239,0,1,3}.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not. Address contains my real ip address (194.x.x.88), not a multicast group address.